# Error "package org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom is declared in module java.xml.crypto, which does not export it"

Tags: java, sha

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.lang.Object;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY;
import org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.Utils;

public class main {

    public void hashText(String s) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] input = s.getBytes();
    byte[] digest = md.digest(input);

    System.out.println("Input: " + s);
    Utils.printByteArray("Digest", digest);
    }
public void demo() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    hashText("hello");
}
}
```

[The error I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8FOD.png)

```
main.java:7: error: package org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom is not visible
import org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.Utils;
                                ^
  (package org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom is declared in module java.xml.crypto, which does not export it)
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

---

There aren't enough resources on the internet for Java Cryptography. I don't have any idea what to try with this error. I think this is an old class that isn't available now in JDK.

PS: This is my first time asking a question here. Please mind the mishap.

Comment: Java 9 introduced the [Module](https://www.oracle.com/in/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) system which allows for better dependency organization and access control.  The package is located in the java.xml.crypto module but has been private to that module and can be used only in that module. You can't use it and in your case since you are simply printing the bytes use an normal for loop or use Arrays.toString() instead of Utils.printByteArray